# Python: *args unpacks, how to repack from test_train_split?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, scipy

I have multiple (type) inputs put inside a list `x` and I'm doing the `test train split` using:

```
x = [some_matrix, scalar_value, something_else, ...]
x0_train, x0_test, x1_train, x1_test, ... , y_train, y_test = 
   train_test_split(x[0],x[1],... , y, test_size=0.2, random_state=np.random, shuffle=True)
```

I managed to change the input parameters `x[0], x[1], ...` to `*x`:

```
x0_train, x0_test, x1_train, x1_test, ... , y_train, y_test = 
   train_test_split(*x, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=np.random, shuffle=True)

    # But I have to manually repack
    x_train = [x0_train, x1_train]
    x_test = [x0_test, x1_test]
```

But is there a way to receive it without having to manually repack? What is the equivalent of:

```
*x_train, *x_test, y_train, y_test = 
   train_test_split(*x, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=np.random, shuffle=True)
```

Or is there any other way to do this? For eg: constructing a dictionary and using ** to unpack, but I still have the same problem. What is the convention anyway (if one exists)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solves the *zigzag split* problem:

```
recv = [None for i in range(2*len(x))]
*recv, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(*x, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=np.random, shuffle=True)

# Edit: credits hpaulj
x_train = recv[::2]
x_test = recv[1::2]
```

---

Also, if there's a way to copy references this will work too

```
x_train = [ None for _ in range(len(x))]
x_test = [ None for _ in range(len(x))]

recv = [item for sublist in zip(x_train, x_test) for item in sublist]
# But unfortunately the above line gives only the values and not references
# Hence doesn't work

*recv, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(*x, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=np.random, shuffle=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Unpacking is just a way of allocating the elements of a list, tuple, or other iterable to several variables.  The normal way to 'repack' is to collect those variables in a list (or tuple):

```
In [48]: a,b,c = [[1,2,3],3,[4,5]]
In [49]: a
Out[49]: [1, 2, 3]
In [50]: b
Out[50]: 3
In [51]: c
Out[51]: [4, 5]
In [52]: [a,b,c]
Out[52]: [[1, 2, 3], 3, [4, 5]]
```

There's minimal cost to this since it is just Python playing with object pointers.  No copies of big data blocks.

I'm not familiar with the details of the `train_test_split` action.  Your inputs and outputs suggest that is doing something like

```
alist = [(x[mask], x[~mask]) for x in xinput]
alist = itertools.chain(*alist)
```

That is, it applies some sort of split, index or sliced, to each of the input `*args`, and then flattens the resulting list.

Newer Pythons have some form of `*` or `...` unpacking, that allocates multiple items to a variable.  I haven't used it much, so would have to look up the docs. But in this case I think you want to collect every-other value in some a list.  I can see doing that with a iteration and list appends.  Using one list comprehension is tricky if not impossible, but two is fine.

'*' syntax in unpacking:

```
In [55]: a, *b = [[1,2,3],3,[4,5]]
In [56]: a
Out[56]: [1, 2, 3]
In [57]: b
Out[57]: [3, [4, 5]]
In [58]: [a,b]
Out[58]: [[1, 2, 3], [3, [4, 5]]]
In [59]: [a,*b]
Out[59]: [[1, 2, 3], 3, [4, 5]]
```

You can't have 2 (or more) starred expressions in an assignment.

---

Inspired by your list comprehensions, here's a another way of collecting ever other item in a list:

```
In [65]: *a, = [1,2,3],[4,5],[10,11,12],[13,14]
In [66]: a
Out[66]: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [10, 11, 12], [13, 14]]
In [67]: a[::2]
Out[67]: [[1, 2, 3], [10, 11, 12]]
In [68]: a[1::2]
Out[68]: [[4, 5], [13, 14]]
```

Comment: what's `mask` in index?

Comment: It's just a standin for however your split function divides the input arrays into train and test array.  I'm guessing it generates a random index or mask, and applies the same one to each input array.  I don't think the details matter for this repacking task.

Comment: I'm clear about using * in assignments, but still trying to understand `alist = [(x[mask], x[~mask]) for x in xinput]`, with those vars `xinput`, `mask`? an example might help...