# Python list comprehension: Getting references in place of values

Tags: list, pointers, reference, list-comprehension

I am trying to get references of `x_train` and `x_test` so that `*ref` in this code

```
x_train = [ None for _ in range(len(x))]
x_test = [ None for _ in range(len(x))]

# criss-cross merge list / zip merge
recv = [item for sublist in zip(x_train, x_test) for item in sublist]
# If x_train was [10,11,12] and x_test was [13,14,15], recv will have [10,13,11,14,12,15]
# But unfortunately the above line gives only the values and not references

*recv, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(*x, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=np.random, shuffle=True)
# values received at *recv to be assigned to x_train[0], x_test[0], x_train[1], x_test[1], ...
```

will directly assign the received values to `x_train` and `x_test` to solve [second part of my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49373787/3125070) by using references in place of list values.

How do I get references or pointers for list elements?

---

EDIT: I understand that python uses pointers internally, but is there a way to do that for list comprehension?

Assignment operation:

```
print('Reference Assignment')
a = [1,2,3]
b = a
b.append(4)
print('a',a)
print('b',b)
```

Output:

```
Reference Assignment
a [1, 2, 3, 4]
b [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

List comprehension:

```
print('List Comprehension')
a = [1,2,3]
b = [item for item in a]
b.append(4)
print('a',a)
print('b',b)
```

Output:

```
List Comprehension
a [1, 2, 3]
b [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Playground [here](https://trinket.io/python3/835e80a78c)

Comment: In Python you don't have pointers. Why don't you iterate over the list, or use indeces?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, Python doesn't give **access** to pointers to devs, however, it should be using them internally. Isn't there a way to get references without explicitly using pointers?

Comment: Actually you have the reference in Python, as every variable you pass are only the references. So you don't need to do the indirection magic in Python as Python will do it for you.

Comment: @AndrásTóth Updated the question

Comment: This is absoluty correct. The first is a refenerce assignment. You assign the same list to a and b.
The second is two different list. You create a second list, and put all the items to it. In this case a and b points to different lists.